# How to reload an aof file into Redis

Tags: redis

our Redis server went down (unsure why, not a server outage) and trying to restart with the pre-existing aof file in place and it wouldn't start getting stuck on the line "Reading RDB preamble from AOF file..."

The server was originally started as follows:
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis -e REDIS_PASSWORD=# -v /var/redis/data:/bitnami/redis/data bitnami/redis:5.0.5-r5
BGREWRITEAOF was enabled so the aof was rewritten by Redis to keep the size lower

Moving the previous AOF file and starting a new container, Redis came up fresh.

I have tried to import the previous AOF using
redis-cli -a # --pipe < previousfile.aof
or
cat previousfil.aof | redis-cli - a # --pipe

But it fails due to the input being too large

redis-check-aof says my previous AOF is invalid, but I wonder it is because the file was compressed with BGREWRITEAOF

I'm stuck with how to move forward.
Can I revert the BGREWRITEAOF to get the raw file?
Can I break the file up in that format and import?
Are there better ways to import Redis data

Thanks